# How to get good results from DB

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a problem with sql query.
I need to get list of users. The problem is the `left join` i use.
this is my query

```
 SELECT  
u.*  
 FROM  
users u LEFT JOIN game g on g.user_id = u.user_id  
LEFT JOIN game_actions ga on ga.game_id = g.id  
LEFT JOIN emails e on e.id = ga.email_id
WHERE  
u.user_id = 0  
AND u.is_contact_by_email = 1 
    AND email.type = 2
```

this query returns the same user more then once because of the join with other tables
i want this query to return each user just one time.
i'm using sql developer.

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there are more games, actions, and emails for each user. How do you imagine the result table to look like? Because when you are selecting only from user table (`SELECT u.*`), then there is no point in joining others. If you need the other tables, use `GROUP BY (u.user_id)` to group rows by user.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're not using game, game_actions, or emails for any purpose (they're not filtering users, and you're not enriching the results with data from either of these tables), there's no need to join those tables at all:

```
SELECT  
  u.*  
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id = 0  
  AND u.is_contact_by_email = 1
```

Comment: i need this join...the end of the query is And email.type = 2

Answer (score 1):

You may group result by `user_id` and use [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html) to return other fields, for eaxmple -

```
SELECT u.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.game_id) games FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN game g
    ON g.user_id = u.user_id  
  LEFT JOIN game_actions ga
    ON ga.game_id = g.id  
  LEFT JOIN emails e
    ON e.id = ga.email_id
WHERE
  u.user_id = 0  AND u.is_contact_by_email = 1
GROUP BY
  u.user_id
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT does not work, i need to do something special for it?

Comment: GROUP BY user_id will show unique users, then other multiple records (with the same user_id) have to be processed with aggregate functions. I have added GROUP_CONCAT as an example, you can use another one - MAX, MIN, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use keyword distinct with your query